# How can I use a function from another class in my React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my `Tools.js`

```
export default class Tools extends React.Component {
    show() {
        console.log(1)
    }
}
```

And this is my `App.js`

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        Tools->show(); // ???
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <Loading />
                <Header />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I want call `show()` function in `componentDidMount()` of `App`

How I can call function from another class into App?

Comment: You'd import your Tool class at the top of the App class file, and then you'd be able to call `show()`

Comment: @JoshuaTerrill i import this: `import Tools from './components/class/Tools';`

Comment: @MattU yes i saw this. but i cant understand it

Comment: Tools.prototype.show() - but you should never do this !. Just define common function in separate file

Comment: @Robert this code work fine. but why i dont use it?

Comment: Because your code will embroiled. Common practice is to separate each common functionality in separate function/class in it's own file. In near function you will forget that this function is used in other components and you will adjust it to this Tools component. This is just really bad practice.

Comment: [sanbox  - check c2 component](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-hypatia-nrbvu?file=/src/C2.js)

Comment: It would be much simpler for you to leverage functional programming to implement composition vs inheritance, as explained here: https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html

Comment: You can do this from technical point of view. And you should not from an architectural point of view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your importing a class you need to instantiate it with `new` then use your show method.

In your App.js:

```
import {Tools} from 'Tools.js';

const myTool = new Tools();

export default class App extends React.Component {
componentDidMount() {
    myTool.show();
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Loading />
            <Header />
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you. Can I access direct to function like php? `Tools::show();` ?